# Cypher Match node that has no relation to any node not in a list

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm struggeling with a Cypher query where I have a list, let's say of People `(['Peter', 'Stacy', 'Olli'])`.
I'm looking for all Persons, that have some of those 3 as their only friends.
So basically I'm trying to `match (p:Person)-[:HAS_FRIEND]->(q:Person) WHERE q.name in ['Peter', 'Stacy', 'Olli']` but i want to exclude those that have at leas one friend that is not in the list.

For example Bobs friends are Peter and Stacy. This means he should be matched.
Jans friends are Stacy, Olli and Bob. He should not be matched since Bob isn't on the list.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly more complex approach should weed out :Persons that have more friends than the required friends that matched to them.

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:HAS_FRIEND]->(friend:Person) 
WHERE friend.name in $friendNames  
WITH p, count(p) as friendHits
WHERE size((p)-[:HAS_FRIEND]->()) = friendHits
RETURN p
```

`friendHits` in this case has a max of the size of the $friendNames collection parameter. They have at least as many friends as `friendHits`. If they have more, then they have friends other than those specified in the input collection, and are filtered out.

The advantage here is that we start expanding from the :Person nodes associated with the friends in the input collection, rather than having to scan all :Persons and their friends in the db, so you're querying a much smaller segment of the db.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using the [ALL](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/predicate/#functions-all) function:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:HAS_FRIEND]->(q:Person)
WITH p, collect(q) as friends
WHERE ALL(friend in friends WHERE friend.name IN ['Peter', 'Stacy', 'Olli'])
RETURN p
```

This Cypher query will return `:Person` nodes that all friends are in the friend list.

Comment: Works as intended. Thank you